# SCALE decode RPC getKeysPaged

Tags: substrate

Background:
The Polkadot App's frontend allows us to call `claimer.lookup`[link](https://github.com/Greenetwork/BLX_chain/blob/230654e0593306f255cc5ff5573617ce5e8083f2/pallets/claimer/src/lib.rs#L322) without any options.  This returns a list of APNs and the associated accounts.
The substrate-frontend-template that we have been building off of requires that we include an option, which does not allow us to get all APNs and accounts.  As a workaround we have tried to make a direct RPC call, but we cannot figure out how to decode the response.

I believe the response is SCALE encoded.  Below is a blog post discussing some of the intricacies of doing this:
https://www.shawntabrizi.com/substrate/querying-substrate-storage-via-rpc/

For the specifics of what we are currently trying you can look in this file:
https://github.com/Greenetwork/BLX_frontend_new/blob/maprefresh/src/MapRefresh.js#L21
The response to `getKeysPaged` call is being decoded by the Polkadot frontend, but I haven't found a way to decode it in our https://github.com/Greenetwork/BLX_frontend_new

example response from chain:

```
[
  "0x2df95c7f7f0d67daa549602785d7beae891ad457bf4da54990fa84a2acb148a20cf935632272b1131281c8c417ea1d513500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "0x2df95c7f7f0d67daa549602785d7beae891ad457bf4da54990fa84a2acb148a21640c3ff7716f6e3d046d710919caccb3434343735380000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "0x2df95c7f7f0d67daa549602785d7beae891ad457bf4da54990fa84a2acb148a229bde7c5407d4c0e698d76543e46e51c3334353039383600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
]
```

decoded result in Polkadot js apps frontend

```
[
  [
    [
      0x3500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    ],
    5Ec3KvnQdwYfLDgZB6JujjatVkHKbzMPQP5YojDAmia8YBuQ
  ],
  [
    [
      0x3434343735380000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    ],
    5EE6fRKB1Drd8cZAVHGuZJHpmQr7bV66Mz2VaXEPJCnJSChw
  ],
  [
    [
      0x3334353039383600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    ],
    5Ew5ExAtUSBEMw96ZMMvS5TsyR7RQfwuve6zpebVYJQDetYZ
  ]
]
```

example front-end-template response that needs to be decoded:
[image: example front-end-template response that needs to be decoded]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further reading of https://www.shawntabrizi.com/substrate/transparent-keys-in-substrate/

the RPC response:

```
0x2df95c7f7f0d67daa549602785d7beae891ad457bf4da54990fa84a2acb148a2a0e98c1569443b450c93febfe626c7683331373035330000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
---------------------- storage prefix key ------------------------+++++++ blake2 128 hash ++++++++------------------------ account id ----------------------------
```

But our `account id` is of type Address32 so we need to do one more lookup and feed account id back into claimer.lookup